# receiving "Oops, try again!" in "computing bill" codeacademy Python exercise

Tags: python

> Write a function compute_bill that takes a parameter food as input and
>   computes your bill by looping through the food list and summing the
>   costs of each item in the list.
>
> For now, go ahead and ignore whether or not the item you're billing
>   for is in stock.
>
> Note that your function should work for any food list.

The Given code is

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
```

I've written this:

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0;
    for f in food:
        if stock[f] > 0:
            total+=prices[f]
            stock[f] -=1

    return total
compute_bill(groceries)
```

Error message is

> Oops, try again! You code does not seem to work when ['apple'] is used as input -- it returns 0 instead of 2.

Comment: It says `For now, go ahead and ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock` But you didn't ignore that.

Comment: Thank You so much @DavidRobinson for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **For now, go ahead and ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock.**

Remove

- `if stock[f] > 0:`
- `stock[f] -= 1`

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you're trying to figure out why your function isn't meeting the requirements of the assignment, the instructions said:

"For now, go ahead and ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock."

Your code checks to make sure that the item is in stock, contrary to the instructions, and thus returns 0 instead of 2.